# Create an admin panel for GAE web app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-apps

I'm newbie in GAE and just trying to work out basic principles of my future web app. So I looking to java to design my app. And I want realize which is better way to create admin panel? An admin should be allowed to manage posts and users for example.

I heard that Django has build-in admin panel, but I do not experienced in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The great thing about going the Python/Django route is that there are great tutorials that walk you through the process step-by-step.

[One example.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/)

[Google's own example of how to get Django running.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel)

[Another example, but be more careful with this one: it's slightly out-of-date.  Still a good reference though.](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html)

If you're comfortable with programming, Python is a very easy language to pickup.  As you mentioned, Django provides a great admin interface that does a lot of the work for you.

If you do decide to use Java, you'll have to build the admin interface from scratch, which generally takes quite a bit of time (if you want to do it right and do it well).  I recommend that you use a framework to help you in the process, and [here Google has some documentation on which frameworks work in GAE.](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava)

Comment: So, do you recommend use Django? May be there is some java libs which providing to create admin room easy?

Comment: As someone who first learned Java and just recently got into Python/Django: absolutely.  Python really is quite easy to learn and the Django tutorials are simple and very helpful.  

As far as Java libs that create Admin interfaces (and are compatible with GAE), I'm not entirely sure.  I did some basic google searching and didn't immediately find anything, but that doesn't mean it may not exist.

Comment: But I experienced in java about a year and very like it. Ok, will see in Django side